# How to do complex layout with scrollview

Tags: android, layout, scrollview

I need to perform this layout:

See image from:
https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-_uW9jKzUY_M/UVWlL2SnNBI/AAAAAAAAAOw/geY-Q-vTsqY/s540/myImage+%283%29.png

- Area 1 is a complex imbrication of linear / relative layouts
- Area 2 is also complex, but would be contained in a scrollview
- Area 3 contains 2 buttons in a vertical linear layout

How this can be achieved?

Comment: wow, I like that style, did you draw it by yourself or there is a tool to generate such preview?

Comment: There's a tool: www.balsamiq.com

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.33"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.33" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="TextView" />
    </ScrollView>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Better to use weightSum="5" on the outer LinearLayout, then the first child can be layout_weight=2, and same as the second. Then the 3rd can be 1.

Comment: My example is a simplified example. The proportions I need are not those of the example. What I would like to have is Area 1 and Area 3 height to be wrap_content, and Area 2 sizing set to remaining space.

Comment: I may misunderstand the layout_weight attribute, but i think it provides kind of percentage of space of the screen. What I need is fixed size (based on content size) for Areas 1 and 3, and have Area 2 (which would be scrollable) size using remaining space.

Comment: So use wrap_content for 1 and 3 area. For 2 use match_parent

Comment: Then, from your example, Area 1 is disappearing, Area 2 is increasing very much and only first button of Area 3 is visible.

Comment: After, if I remove weight attributes, Only Area 1 and 2 are visible.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer myself.

I have to use the layout_above attribute and a main RelativeLayout.

See this example:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/footer"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView1" />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="TextView2" />

        </LinearLayout>   
    </ScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/footer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button2" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```